# Do we need server if using hash strategy of routing in Angular2?

Tags: routes, angular

Do we need server if using hash strategy of routing in Angular2 (for example, use node http-server) or just open index.html?

Comment: No, with hash strategy you don't. you always point to `index.html#something...` so in reality you always access index.html, and the path after the hashtag tells the page how to render the page.

Comment: but if you want to remove the `#` sign from your `url` then it need to server side rendering using any of server like `nginx` etc. also known as pathLocationstretagy.

Comment: Thanks. Then do you know which strategy is better than another?

Comment: both are good its depend on us which is requires as per need. basically mostly people use HashLocation because it avoids page refresh problem

Comment: None, they're just different. They each might be better in different cases, if you want to use Angular 2 router and your app is just a client app that doesn't need backend at all then you might be better off using hashtag approach if you don't mind loosing the functionality the hashtag does in HTML. If you already have a backend might as well use the default strategy that allows the end user to see the paths as regular files path.

Comment: Thanks langley. What do you mean by "loosing the functionality the hashtag does in HTML"? What kind of functionality hashtag will lose? Usually the big project in industry should have backend, does that mean it's better to use default strategy in that situation?

Answer (score 0):

You always need a server. With `PathLocationStrategy` you need a server that also rewrites requests.

The browser has serious restrictions when loading files from disk because of security concerns and this will prevent the Angular2 app to load properly.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends. For example it will fail to run, due to security concerns, on Chrome (v48).

A lot of it will work but you will have to test a lot on different browsers to make sure that your app will run on the browsers you need to support.

Using the HashStrategy will get you past the most obvious problem, but not past all problems. If you need to continue down this road, please update your questions with the functionalities that do not work without a server. This would really help out others, thanks.